# How to merge two makefiles?

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

I'm not so skilled with makefile and I'm getting some configuration problem in marging two different makefiles.
I've two directories with different projects, made up by several .c/.cpp files and one makefile for each project.
I would like to drop file1.c of project A to project B, obviously I can't simply drop the file but I've to change correctly make file of project B.
**MAKEFILE project A:**

```
DESTDIR ?=
PREFIX ?= /usr/local

MAKEFLAGS := -k

CFLAGS := -O2 -Wall -Wno-parentheses

CPPFLAGS += \
    -Iinclude \
    -DAF_CAN=PF_CAN \
    -DPF_CAN=29 \
    -DSO_RXQ_OVFL=40 \
    -DSCM_TIMESTAMPING_OPT_STATS=54 \
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 \
    -D_GNU_SOURCE

PROGRAMS_CANGW := \
    cangw

PROGRAMS_ISOTP := \
    isotpdump \
    isotpperf \
    isotprecv \
    isotpsend \
    isotpserver \
    isotpsniffer \
    isotptun

PROGRAMS_J1939 := \
    j1939acd \
    j1939cat \
    j1939spy \
    j1939sr \
    testj1939

PROGRAMS_SLCAN := \
    slcan_attach \
    slcand

PROGRAMS := \
    $(PROGRAMS_CANGW) \
    $(PROGRAMS_ISOTP) \
    $(PROGRAMS_J1939) \
    $(PROGRAMS_SLCAN) \
    asc2log \
    bcmserver \
    can-calc-bit-timing \
    canbusload \
    candump \
    canfdtest \
    cangen \
    cansequence \
    canlogserver \
    canplayer \
    cansend \
    cansniffer \
    log2asc \
    log2long \
    mcp251xfd-dump \
    slcanpty

all: $(PROGRAMS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAMS) *.o

install:
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
    cp -f $(PROGRAMS) $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin

distclean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAMS) $(LIBRARIES) *.o *~

asc2log.o:  lib.h
canbusload.o:   lib.h
candump.o:  lib.h
cangen.o:   lib.h
canlogserver.o: lib.h
canplayer.o:    lib.h
cansend.o:  lib.h
cansequence.o:  lib.h
log2asc.o:  lib.h
log2long.o: lib.h
j1939acd.o: libj1939.h
j1939cat.o: libj1939.h
j1939spy.o: libj1939.h
j1939sr.o:  libj1939.h
testj1939.o:    libj1939.h
canframelen.o:  canframelen.h

asc2log:    asc2log.o   lib.o
candump:    candump.o   lib.o
cangen:     cangen.o    lib.o
canlogserver:   canlogserver.o  lib.o
canplayer:  canplayer.o lib.o
cansend:    cansend.o   lib.o
cansequence:    cansequence.o   lib.o
log2asc:    log2asc.o   lib.o
log2long:   log2long.o  lib.o
j1939acd:   j1939acd.o  libj1939.o
j1939cat:   j1939cat.o  libj1939.o
j1939spy:   j1939spy.o  libj1939.o
j1939sr:    j1939sr.o   libj1939.o
testj1939:  testj1939.o libj1939.o
canbusload: canbusload.o    canframelen.o

mcp251xfd-dump: mcp251xfd/mcp251xfd-dev-coredump.o mcp251xfd/mcp251xfd-dump.o mcp251xfd/mcp251xfd-main.o mcp251xfd/mcp251xfd-regmap.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

**MAKEFILE project B:**

```
PROG = validNet
COMPILER = g++
STD = c++17
FILES.CPP = GUI.cpp Pipe.cpp
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
LIBS =  `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
WARNING_FLAGS = -w

${PROG}: ${PROG}.cpp
    
    time ${COMPILER} -std=${STD} ${WARNING_FLAGS} ${CFLAGS} ${PROG}.cpp ${FILES.CPP} -o ${PROG} ${LIBS}

clean: 
    rm ${PROG}
```

in particular I just need to use cangen.c in project B for an university project.
Can I simply drop cangen.o in project B directory and linking it as an object file? Is it bad practise?
Is there some simple way to marge two makefile? It's look simple but I haven't find a correct solution, I've tried with this makefile:

```
PROG = validNet
COMPILER = g++ -Wall -Wno-parentheses
STD = c++17
FILES.CPP = GUI.cpp Pipe.cpp cangen.c lib.c
CPPFLAGS += \
    -Iinclude \
    -DAF_CAN=PF_CAN \
    -DPF_CAN=29 \
    -DSO_RXQ_OVFL=40 \
    -DSCM_TIMESTAMPING_OPT_STATS=54 \
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 \
    -D_GNU_SOURCE

CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
LIBS =  `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
WARNING_FLAGS = -w

${PROG}: ${PROG}.cpp
    
    time ${COMPILER} -std=${STD} {$CPPFLAGS} ${WARNING_FLAGS} ${CFLAGS} ${PROG}.cpp ${FILES.CPP} -o ${PROG} ${LIBS}

clean: 
    rm ${PROG}
```

EDIT:

I solved this problem at the end, the issues wasn't in the Makefile but in the .cpp, I forgot to make the include of some libraries

Comment: What about creating a 3rd makefile, which just includes the other two providing the correct directory contexts?

Comment: I thought something similar, is it possible to directly use the object file generated by the compilation of the original Makefile?

Comment: It's probably easier to collect the object files into statically linkable libs.

Comment: how can i make this?

Comment: Using `ar` (`${AR}`). You should at least  know how your compiler toolchain works.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description we can help with.  Please edit your question to show the _exact_ command make invoked, and the error messages you got.  Offhand it doesn't seem like a makefile problem but who knows?!?!

Comment: It's definitely not "easier" to create a static library.  There's nothing "easier" than compiling and linking the entire program with a single command.  Of course, there are many downsides such as you have to recompile all the code if any file changes.  But, the first thing is to make it work, the second thing is to make it better.

Comment: I just solved this issue, I'm updating the original answer